# OldeDb object exception in C#

Tags: c#, oledb

This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:

> ```
> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionInternal.OleDbConnectionInternal(System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionString, System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection)
>     System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions, System.Data.Common.DbConnectionPoolKey, object, System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool, System.Data.Common.DbConnection)
>     System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions, System.Data.Common.DbConnectionPoolKey, object, System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool, System.Data.Common.DbConnection, System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions)
>     System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(System.Data.Common.DbConnection, System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPoolGroup, System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions)
>     System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(System.Data.Common.DbConnection, System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSource<System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal>, System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions, System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal, out System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal)
>     System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(System.Data.Common.DbConnection, System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory, System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSource<System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal>, System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions)
>     System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(System.Data.Common.DbConnection, System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory, System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSource<System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal>, System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions)
>     System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.OpenConnection(System.Data.Common.DbConnection, System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory)
>     System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection.Open()
>     WindowsFormsApp1.DB_Connect.DB_Fields() in DB_Connect.cs
>     ...
>     [Call Stack Truncated]
> ```

It was working Till yesterday now it is not working, can someone please guide me what is wrong in the following code:

```
public static string[] DB_Fields()
{

String[] s = new string[21];
int i = 0, res1;
string s1 = "-";

            string con = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Mu\Desktop\9-50070_000018.csv;" + @"Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=No;'";
            using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(con))
            {
                connection.Open();
                OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("select * from [9-50070_000018.csv$]", connection);
                using (OleDbDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        var data = dr[0];
                        //Console.WriteLine(data);
                        res1 = Strings.InStr(data.ToString(), s1, CompareMethod.Text);
                        //MessageBox.Show(res1.ToString());
                        //MessageBox.Show(data.ToString());
                        if (res1 == 0)
                        {
                            s[i] = data.ToString();
                            i++;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return s;
        }
```

Comment: Use the `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` or `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0` instead of `Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0`. When you open a CSV file, the connection string contains the **Directory Path**, not the **.csv file name** and the Extended Properties do not specify `Excel 8.0`, but `text`. The query, `SELECT * FROM`, specifies the file name, not an Excel-like sheet like this `[9-50070_000018.csv$]`. + (more problems) -- See the different examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54352568/7444103)

Comment: Can you please write a proper statement ?

Comment: I have followed your given link and still I am getting error for connection.Open

Comment: Can you open the file with Notepad?  Did the data change in the file recently?  Did you do any windows updates recently?

Comment: I have changed the connection string as Jimi guidance now I am getting invalid path error, where as my path is right.