# How to see a number with more than 15 characters in a DataGridView?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, csv-import

I'm trying to import from a CSV file into DataGridView a number that is longer than 15 characters. In the CSV file it looks like `8940012004412026012`but after import in the DataGridView is presented as `8.9400120044120259E + 18`.

This is my present code:

```
public static DataTable GetDataTable(string strFileName)
{
    ADODB.Connection oConn = new ADODB.Connection();
    oConn.Open("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0; Data Source = " + System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(strFileName) + "; Extended Properties = \"Text;HDR=YES;FMT=Delimited\";", "", "", 0);
    string strQuery = "SELECT * FROM [" + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(strFileName) + "]";
    ADODB.Recordset rs = new ADODB.Recordset();
    System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    rs.Open(strQuery, "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0; Data Source = " + System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(strFileName) + "; Extended Properties = \"Text;HDR=YES;FMT=Delimited\";",
        ADODB.CursorTypeEnum.adOpenForwardOnly, ADODB.LockTypeEnum.adLockReadOnly, 1);
    adapter.Fill(dt, rs);
    return dt;
}

private void Import()
{
    if (textBox4.Text.Trim() != string.Empty)
    {
        try
         {
            DataTable ct = GetDataTable(textBox4.Text);
            dataGridView2.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
            dataGridView2.DataSource = ct;
            dataGridView2.Columns[0].HeaderCell.Value = "1";
            dataGridView2.Columns[1].HeaderCell.Value = "2";
            dataGridView2.Columns[2].HeaderCell.Value = "3";
           
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

```
dataGridView2.Columns[2].HeaderCell.Value = "3";
```

needs to be `8940012004412026012`

Comment: 1) Do you have more than one data type in that csv column? Maybe many `sting` or `""` and few `long` values? Show us a some lines from that csv file. 2) Why do you use `ADODB.Connection` instead of `OleDbConnection`? [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1050278/14171304). 3) You shouldn't call `Application.DoEvents();` method. To avoid blocking the UI thread, use `async` task to create and return the `DataTable`. 4) You should call `fdlg.Dispose();` at the end of the `button60` event handler.

Comment: Change it into a string/read it as a string?

Comment: I tried to change it to a string but was unsuccessful

Comment: Read the notes here: [OpenFileDialog can't load CSV files but can load xls/xlsx Excel files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54352568/7444103). See the `IMEX` and `Schema.ini` stuff. Ditch ADODB, that's too ancient. -- Possibly, use an existing tool as [CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/) to handle your CSV data, it's a more complex task than it appears at first glance.

Comment: Also, specify what this means: *`dataGridView2.Columns[5].HeaderCell.Value = "6";` needs to be 8940012004412026012*  -- Are you actually referring to the Header Cell or to the Cells of Column n°6?

Comment: The Header Cell is 6 and and the cells needs to be 8940012004412026012

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestion to use CsvHelper this is the solution i found

```
 private void button60_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog fdlg = new OpenFileDialog();
        fdlg.Title = "Select file";
        fdlg.InitialDirectory = @"c:\";
        fdlg.FileName = textBox4.Text;
        fdlg.Filter = "Text and CSV Files(*.txt, *.csv)|*.txt;*.csv|Text Files(*.txt)|*.txt|CSV Files(*.csv)|*.csv|All Files(*.*)|*.*";
        fdlg.FilterIndex = 1;
        fdlg.RestoreDirectory = true;
        if (fdlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(fdlg.FileName))
            using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))

            {
                using (var dr = new CsvDataReader(csv))
                {
                    var dt = new DataTable();
                    dt.Load(dr);
                    dataGridView2.DataSource = dt;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```